# Firebase web keeps duplicating apexchart everytime data is updated

Tags: javascript, firebase

Hey all i am using javascript with ApexCharts to draw a chart and this chart gets its data from firebase but each time the data is changed in firebase instead of replacing the chart or updating it it appends new chart under it

this is the code

```
function dailyTracking(){ 
var query = firebase.database().ref('Facilities').on('value', function(snapshot) {

var options = {
  chart: {
      height: 380,


      width: "100%",
      type: "bar",
      stacked: false
  },
  series: [
      {
          name: "Library",
          data: snapshotToArray(snapshot.child('Library'))
      },
      {
          name: "Canteen",
          data: [5]
      },
      {
          name: "Free Lab",
          data: [42]
      }
  ],
  xaxis: {
    labels: {
      formatter: function (value, timestamp) {
        return new Date() // The formatter function overrides format property
      }, 
    }
  }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

chart.render();
query.off();
return snapshotToArray(snapshot);});}
```

Comment: When you are rendering in the same event, you should first call the `chart.destroy()` if the chart exists to prevent duplication.

Comment: thanks the problem is solved by clearing the container of the chart before rendering using innerHtml

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by adding this line

> ```
> document.getElementById('chart').innerHTML = '';
> ```
>
> before rendering the chart

Comment: The `chart.destroy()` function would also do the same, preventing any possibility of memory leaks. I would recommend using chart.destroy() by checking `if(!chart) chart.destroy()` to be safe :)

Answer (score 0):

Try not to wrap the `chart.render()` call in the event. Render the chart once and call the update event when you get new data by calling [chart.updateSeries()](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#updateSeries)